# What happens if you don't shake the polaroid photo in Uncharted 4

Tags: uncharted-4

In chapter 16 of Uncharted 4 there is a moment when Sam finds a Polaroid camera and takes a picture of himself and Drake. He then gives it to you and you have the option to shake it so that the colors appear and the more you do it the better it becomes. If I recall correctly you have the option of putting the photo away immediately.

Near the end of the game you see the photo again. Does it differ depending on how much you shook it in chapter 16, or is there a perfect photo no matter what you did?

Answer (score 3):

I'm two years late, but I just finished the game without shaking the photo, and it was fully developed at the end of the game. Friendly reminder here that this isn't how Polaroids work, and shaking photos can damage them and the development process.